# Array Sum with Multidimensional Array using Array Filter PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Actually I have the Array Value**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [total_amount] => 4080 [supplier] => 81 ) 
        [249] => Array ( [total_amount] => 8400 [supplier] => 81 ) 
        [466] => Array ( [total_amount] => 20340 [supplier] => 82 ) 
        [519] => Array ( [total_amount] => 2100 [supplier] => 83 ) 
        [1078] => Array ( [total_amount] => 40199 [supplier] => 83 )  
 )
```

and I expecting the output (Sum of total amount of each supplier)

```
 Array ( [81] => 12480 
        [82] =>  20340
        [83] =>  42299   
        )
```

and i tried the following code

```
$new = array_filter($array, function ($var) { return ($var['supplier'] += $var['total_amount']);   });
```

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $a) {   // $arr is your initial array
    (isset($result[$a['supplier']]))? 
        $result[$a['supplier']] += $a['total_amount'] 
        : $result[$a['supplier']] = $a['total_amount'];
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [81] => 12480
    [82] => 20340
    [83] => 42299
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` is not designed for task like this, use `array_walk` insted like:

```
$new = [];
array_walk($array, function ($var) use (&$new) {
    if(isset($new[$var['supplier']])){
        $new[$var['supplier']] += $var['total_amount'];
    }else{
        $new[$var['supplier']] = $var['total_amount'];
    }
});
```